# SignalR on .NET Can't send a derived class or an implementation of an interface to client

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, signalr

everyone. I'm currently trying to send a derived class (or an implementation of an interface) from the server to the client. I can't do it because it won't call the method in the client. I've tried taking out the inheritance and sending it, and it does work properly, so the problem comes from trying to send a derived class to the client. Thanks in advance

Here are the classes:

**Interface:**

```
public interface ISquare
{
    Uri Image
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    List<Player> PlayerList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**Implementations:**

```
public class Property: ISquare
{
    private Uri image { get; set; }
    private List<Player> playerList { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int nHouses { get; set; }
    public bool hasHotel { get; set; }
    public bool isBought { get; set; }
    public ColorProperty color { get; set; }
    public int moneyToPay { get; set; }
    public Player buyer { get; set; }
    public int squarePosition { get; set; }
    public Uri Image
    {
        get
        {
            return image;
        }

        set
        {
            image = value;
        }
    }
    public List<Player> PlayerList
    {
        get
        {
            return playerList;
        }

        set
        {
            playerList = value;
        }
    }

    public Property(int price, int nHouses, bool hasHotel, bool isBought, ColorProperty color, int moneyToPay, Player buyer, int squarePosition, Uri image, List<Player> playerList)
    {
        this.price = price;
        this.nHouses = nHouses;
        this.hasHotel = hasHotel;
        this.isBought = isBought;
        this.color = color;
        this.dineroAPagar = moneyToPay;
        this.buyer = buyer;
        this.squarePosition = squarePosition;
        this.image = image;
        this.playerList = playerList;
    }

    public Property(int price, ColorPropiedad color, int squarePosition)
    {
        this.price = price;
        this.nHouses = 0;
        this.hasHotel = false;
        this.isBought = false;
        this.color = color;
        this.dineroAPagar = 0;
        this.buyer = null;
        this.squarePosition = squarePosition;
        this.image = image;
        this.playerList = new List<Player>();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Square : ISquare
{
    private Uri image { get; set; }
    public SquareType type { get; set; }
    private List<Player> playerList { get; set; }
    public Uri Image
    {
        get
        {
            return image;
        }

        set
        {
            image = value;
        }
    }
    public List<Player> playerList 
    {
        get
        {
            return playerList ;
        }

        set
        {
            playerList = value;
        }
    }

    public Square(SquareType type, List<Player> playerList)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.playerList = playerList;
    }

    public Square(SquareType type)
    {
        this.image = null;
        this.type = type;
        this.playerList= new List<Player>();
    }

    public Square()
    {
        this.image = null;
        this.type = SquareType.PROPERTY;
        this.playerList = new List<Player>();
    }
}
```

**Here's what the client looks like:**

```
private async void joinGame(Player playerServer)
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        {
            if (playerServer != null)
            {
                _navigationService.Navigate(
                    typeof(GameView),
                    new PlayerWithLobby()
                    {
                        player = playerServer,
                        lobby = _lobby
                    }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("Player is null");
            }
        }
        );
    }
```

Comment: What does the client-side code look like?

Comment: There, I edited question to add the client-side code